# Is there a way to pull historical options data using yahoo finance from pandas datareader?

Tags: python, yahoo-finance, pandas-datareader

I am doing a research project and trying to pull options prices from various companies over the past 10 or so years.  It would be even better if I could get volume, open interest and other metrics as well.  Please let me know if the Yahoo Finance package is able to do this!  If not, other suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This;

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web 
import datetime as dt
import sys 

try:
    stock = sys.argv[1]
except:
    raise ValueError('Please provide stock code as argument')

start = dt.datetime(1999, 1, 1)
end = dt.datetime.now()

try:
    df = web.DataReader(stock, 'yahoo', start, end)

    df.to_csv(f"{stock}.csv")
except:
    raise ValueError('Stock not found')
```

Comment: Really appreciate the response!  I am actually trying to get similar datasets for at-the-money options on particular securities.  Any ideas there?

Comment: I just implemented this, and it only shows the stock price's A) high, B) low, C)Open, D) Close, E) Volume, and F) Adj Close